# Switching from C# to C++. Any must-reads?

Tags: c#, c++

I'm trying to find a least-resistance path from C# to C++, and while I feel I handle C# pretty well after two solid years, I'm still not sure I've gotten the "groove" of C++, despite numerous attempts.

Are there any particular books or websites that might be suitable for this transition?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I recommend *The C++ Programming language* by Bjarne Stroustrup. It's not a suitable book for new programmers, but I found it quite effective as programmer who was experienced in other languages and didn't want to waste too much time with learning how while loops work. It's a dense but quite comprehensive book.

Comment: That sounds like an excellent reason to choose that book. Just what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 17):

About two years ago, I made the switch from C# to C++ (after 10 years of writing java). The most useful book for me was Bruce Eckel's *Thinking in C++* [[AMZN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0139798099)]. You can also read the book online at [Eckel's website](http://mindview.net/Books/DownloadSites). It's a well-written book--the kind you can read in bed--that's also useful as a keyboard-side reference. It assumes a significant level of comfort with OO and general programming concepts.

Stroustrup [[AMZN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201700735)] is invaluable as a reference, but basically impenetrable unless you're trying to answer a very specific question--and even then, it's a struggle. I haven't cracked my K&R [[AMZN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131103628)] in a few years. I don't think it's got much value as a C++ reference. Myers' *Effective C++* [[AMZN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321334876)] (and, once you get there, *Effective STL* [[AMZN](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201749629)]) are fantastic books. They're very specific, though (e.g., "36. Design functor classes for pass-by-value"), and hence not as useful as Eckel for making the transition.

My experience writing C++ after many years writing managed languages has been great. C++ is a hundred times more expressive than C#, and extremely satisfying to write--where it's warranted. On the other hand, on the rare occasions when I still get to write C#, I'm always amazed by how quickly and succinctly I can get things done.

Anyway, Eckel's *Effective C++* can help you make the transition. There's a second volume that's good, but not as good. Stick with the original.

Good luck!

Comment: I think you mean the book "Thinking in C++" by Bruce Eckel, which is where the corresponding link leads to.

Answer (score 7):

I suggest you to read [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.research.att.com/~bs/3rd.html) book (written by Bjarne Stroustrup). It may not be the best book to begin with, but it is definitely on you should read, sooner or later.

Comment: Dammit, you were just ahead of me. Oh well…

Comment: Yeah, that can be some what frustrating :)

Comment: Mr. Jankovic, I want to contact you. How can i do this? I have a problem about your project. Please help me.

Answer (score 5):

Anything written by [Meyers](http://www.aristeia.com/books.html), recommended by [same](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/top_cpp_books.html), or written by [Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/).

Answer (score 3):

Accelerated C++ by Koenig (**Edit**: and Moo.)

Answer (score 1):

They are fundamentally very different beasts so there is no least resistance path between. However I recommend you to read http://www.phpcompiler.org/doc/virtualinheritance.html beforehand in case you ever need a non-trivial inheritance. It can save you a few headaches.

Answer (score 1):

The C++ Programming Language by Bjarne Stroustrup is a must read. Effective C++ (Scott Meyers) is another book I found helpful.

And to balance all this, read the C++ FQA ( http://yosefk.com/c++fqa/ ) - while not a book, it's a valuable resource, and I wish I had access to it when I was getting started with C++. Just don't let it discourage you.

Answer (score 1):

I found Lippman et al's "C++ Primer: 4th edition" to be excellent.  It emphasizes STL usage, best practices, and auto_ptr usage from the very first.  I went from a Java position to a C++ assignment, and it was really excellent.

As a pure reference, Josuttis's "The C++ Standard Library" was STL at its best (and worst...the guy really doesn't pull punches)

Lastly, Meyer's Effective C++, as others have said is a must-read for the "gotchas" inherent in C++

Answer (score 1):

This is a list of books that are recommended by the folks over in #C++ EFNet: http://rafb.net/efnet_cpp/books/

Answer (score 0):

I'd consider [K&R](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language_(book)) a prerequisite for C++.  Perhaps the best thing about C++ is that it's a better C.

And of course, Stroustrup (as suggested by Mladen Jankovic) is a must read.

Answer (score 0):

My two standard books are "Object-Oriented Programming in C++", Third Edition, by Robert LaFore, published by The Waite Group, and "C++ from the Ground Up" by Herbert Shildt, published by Osborne McGraw-Hill.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of Lafore at all.  Am reading it now, and while it is very good about the elements of C++, it gives absolutely no guidance about what is good practice or not.  The functional chapters explain globals as just another way to pass data into a function, with nary a warning that there might be a better way.

Answer (score 0):

You should read one of the other books posted, but then also [The Design & Evolution of C++](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201543303).  It helps you to get inside the head of what the language is trying to do.